# Access the public, bindable variable from one .MXML in another .MXML

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have as a main application setted "main.mxml"
which contains the follow declaration :

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source="../images/common/user.png")] 
public var userIcon : Class;
```

I have another module, on which i wish to access it as a button icon.
I have tried with the follow definition, but it doesnt work:

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="29">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button id="buttonLoad" width="80%" label="Loading" icon="{ main.userIcon }"/>
</s:Group>
```

- How to access the declaration inside main.mxml from the other modules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of MXML class isn't an identifier of its instance (because of it can have a lot of instances). You should think about MXML files as not files but classes. They are absolutely the same as ordinary ActionScript classes. The same rules as in other OOP languages. So if you have `main.mxml` `main` is a class name for that class and its package is determined by that MXML file path relative to the source folder (as in ActionScript classes). That's why you should name your MXML classes from the capital letter (`Main.mxml` but not `main.mxml`).

If your `main.mxml` is top level application you can refer it as `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication`. But it is not the right way to do things.

The best way is to inject this property to your target class. You can do it using Dependency Injecting Framework/Container like [Spring ActionScript](http://www.springactionscript.org/) or [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) or [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/). Or you can do it manually by delegating from top application to the class containing piece of code which handles modules. When module is loaded pass this value there.

Comment: i don't wish to use 3rd party frameworks. So - there isn't any way to access one modules variables from another ? ( except public static way i mean )

Comment: I described the way: delegation of the property through object's hierarchy.

Comment: I am not understanding. Please, could you show me some example ?

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev When you say "Modules" are you using the term generically, or are you creating aspects of your application with the Module class  ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/modules/Module.html )

Comment: nope. i am sorry about the missunderstooding, it is used generically. i am encapsulating some visual components into a separate "module" because they could be reused lately, but they is derived from "Group" and they is Components, not Modules.

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev If your modules are not modules but just components (please be careful in terms!) my answer is more than comprehensive about it. So you have at least two good ways: dependency injection and delegation. And at least one bad way: global (static) access. As far as you don't want to understand injection and delegation principles, which are basic in OOP architecture to get low coupling, I recommend you to use global access. Don't be perfectionist! You'll get experience step by step. Now you've heard terms but next project it is probably you'll be able to apply them. So use statics.

Comment: never worked with dependancy injection with delphi... which is probably the greath wall before me. I am comming from delphi development to flex, which is hudge difference seems like. :| Thank you about the points, seems like i didnt understand before what u were talking about. I will step with globals then. I hope they will be not some performance issue or something. :|

Comment: With the performance point of view using static global access is the best way. But it is not good from architectural point of view because provides high coupling between components. The best option to use statics with more or less acceptable architecture in your case is to extract that static constant into separate class which will contain only that kind of static constants. And use that class everywhere.